# Difference Viro React and Viro React Hybrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm experimenting with ViroReact and came across this page:

https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/code-samples

It shows two github hosted examples and describes one as a "React Native Hybrid".

I'm trying to understand the differences between the two projects, what are their respective limitations / requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a developer on the Viro team and I'd be happy to answer your question.

Viro React, through the use of the `Viro(AR)SceneNavigator` components, allow you to add an AR/VR view to your React Native (or existing) Android and iOS applications. As a result, most, if not all of our components, are meant to be for creating 3D AR/VR scenes and not 2D elements (which React Native is meant to do).

The differences between the code samples is that samples hosted at [viro](https://github.com/viromedia/viro) are meant to be self-contained VR/AR samples to show off how various Viro components work.

The sample at [ViroARSampleApp](https://github.com/viromedia/ViroARSampleApp) is a more complex application which leverages React Native for 2D UI components alongside the Viro components for AR. This will show you how you might use Viro with React Native to build a fully fledged application.

Let us know if you have any questions, you can keep posting here, on our GitHub [issues](https://github.com/viromedia/viro/issues) page, or, for more private questions, contact us via this [Contact link](https://viromedia.com/contact-1/) on our website.